# How do I show Ubuntu Dock always over maximized windows (without the need for autohide and mouseover)?

Tags: window, ubuntu-dock

I will be clear and brief:

currently modified settings: (I am happy with this)

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock extend-height false
```

(i.e. no other significant things have been modified (except for bottom placement, but you can see that))

What I want On window Maximize (got it by fluke but it never remains like this):

[image: wanted maximize behaviour]

What is happening now on window Maximize:
[image: current maximize behaviour]

I don't mean the 2 monitor dock, but the maximize around the edges of the dock and not only to the height of the dock. hope i was clear.

Comment: ummm... I don't have Settings > Dock  .  https://i.imgur.com/0QpHRKL.png

Comment: done with imgur

Comment: First run `gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock dock-fixed false`. Then run `gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock autohide true`. Does that work?

Comment: yes, I think so. But I did also do an "sudo apt-get install gnome" right after install, because I didn't like some things about vanilla, but yes, now I think I logged in a vanilla session. let me log out. brb. thx for the help btw.

Comment: first answer: I have 5 options on login: "Gnome, Gnome Classic, Gnome on Xorg, Ubuntu, Ubuntu on Wayland". I am logged into option 1 "Gnome"

Comment: 2nd answer. running the commands makes window maximize behave properly and on mouseover it looks great. But I want it to be like that permanently without the need for a mouseover except in fullscreen gaming, obviously, where I don't want to see it)

Comment: mouse over dock area: exactly what I want. https://i.imgur.com/txeoIb4.png  but I want it like that always without the need to mouse-over

Comment: That is currently not possible as far as I know. Either you'll have to leave the dock always there occupying the space (as in your 2nd screenshot) or you'll have to activate auto-hiding which will show the dock only on mouse hover when you have maximised windows/

Answer (score 3):

there is a way around,you need set auto hide delay time to a big number like 9999999,
you can do it from dconf editor,

1. open dconf editor
2. go to /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-dock/hide-delay
3. turn off default value and put a big number in custom value

or from terminal

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock extend-height false
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock autohide true

gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock hide-delay 9999999
```

Comment: also, u need to give pressure to bring back dash from hidden condition,do as below to use no pressure, minimize pressure-threshold and show delay as musch as possible

Comment: I think this answer should be accepted because it solves the OP's problem perfectly, though it seems a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

What you are apparently looking for, i.e. the dock appearing above a focused windows, is currently not supported in Dash to Dock, and accordingly also not in Ubuntu Dock, which is based on Dash to Dock.

Next section refers to changing the settings using the Dash to Dock settings dialogs. The closest you will get is by turning Intelligent autohide on, then in the "Intelligent autohide customisation", make sure "Dodge Windows is on and set to "Only focussed application windows". Then the dock will show up unless the active window would cover it.